# Using Azure CLI to manage API Management (APIM) Users, Products, Certificates, APIs

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-cli, ibm-api-management, apim

It seems that this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest) contains all the functionality that Azure CLI supports in regard to Azure API Management. But it doesn't show how to manage entities such as users, products, certificates, subscriptions, and APIs using Azure CLI.

Does Azure CLI lack these functionalities or is there a way to manage those entities using Azure CLI? Can Azure CLI be considered as a replacement for ARM templates in the case of APIM?

Answer (score 2):

Azure CLI is missing those. Please raise on aka.ms/apimwish

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, the Azure CLI API management command is in preview. SO it will miss some commands. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli?toc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-cli-latest#august-27-2019). So if you want to manage Azure API management entities such as users, products, certificates, subscriptions, and APIs, I suggest you use Azure PowerShell to do that : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/?view=azps-3.0.0.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Azure CLI currently seems to support this, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/api?view=azure-cli-latest#az-apim-api-create) for Microsoft docs. Make sure you upgrade your CLI to the latest version to be able to leverage this.

To get the CLI docs:

```
az apim --help
```